# wxRegexp need to catch a separate n-digit sequence where the 1sr symbol is not zero

Tags: regex, wxwidgets

It is quite easy to catch exactly n symbols, but how to filter the 1st one to b sure it is in range [1-9] not [0-9]? I can't find out how to extract such strings using wxRegEx(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks! one small issue here: how can i make sure this pattern matches the exactly n-digit string? i tested you pattern. w/ n=7 Matches() returns true for "123456789" sample, and i need 'true' only for "1234567".

Comment: @user1053031: Try to add word boundaries: `\\b[1-9][0-9]{x}\\b`

Comment: Thank you, but still fails( i'm passing 100000 and reseive false along w/ false for 999999 value(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[1-9][0-9]{n-1}$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/38

Comment: Thanks a lot! this one passes my samples. i need to put the regexp in my learning plan asap...

Comment: @user1053031 try regex101.com .its an awesume site to learn regex.And of course SO is here :)